# php add x weeks to a date and then find the next given day

Tags: php

I can add x week to my date

```
//$ultima_azione <--- 2015/07/15
//$data['intervallo'] <---- 5

$mydate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($ultima_azione." +".$data['intervallo']." weeks"));
```

now how can i give a day starting from that week 
example:

```
//$mydate + "next Monday" -----> final date
```

and this ve to work like, if today is Monday and i add weeks to jump to an other Monday and then i select the next Monday the week don't ve to change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `strtotime`. It can do date calculations based on a textual representation of the delta:

```
$mydate = strtotime('+3 weeks');
```

It also accepts a second parameter, which is a timestamp to start from when doing the calculation, so after you get the offset in weeks, you can pass the new date to a second calculation:

```
// Get three weeks from 'now' (no explicit time given)
$mydate = strtotime('+3 weeks');

// Get the Monday after that.
$mydate = strtotime('next Monday', $mydate);
```

See [`strtotime` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for more examples of notations that you can use.

Comment: Two anonymous downvotes in two days, on a 3 year old answer.. If something is wrong or if the answer is outdated please leave a note. AFAIK this function still exists in PHP 7, and I'm not aware that it is deprecated in favor something else.

Comment: Still works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using PHP's built-in `DateTime` class for any date and time logic. It's a much better API than the older date and time functions and creates much cleaner and easier to read code.

For example:

```
// Current date and number of weeks to add
$date = '2015/07/15';
$weeks = 3;

// Create and modify the date.
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $date);
$dateTime->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($weeks . ' weeks'));
$dateTime->modify('next monday');

// Output the new date.
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

References:

- [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).
- [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- [DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)
- [DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)
- [DateInterval::createFromDateString](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php)
- [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$today = time();

$weeks = 2;
// timestamp 2 weeks from now
$futureWeeks = strtotime("+ ".$weeks." weeks");
// the next monday after the timestamp date
$futureMonday = strtotime("next monday",$futureWeeks);
echo date("Y-m-d", $futureMonday);
// or in one line
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("next monday", strtotime("+ ".$weeks." weeks")));
```

PHP is using an unix timestamp for date calculations. Functions as [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) using a timestamp as an optional second parameter. This is used a reference for formatting and calculations. If no timestamp is passed to the function the current timestamp is used ([time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)).

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer here. This will show the next wednesday every 2 weeks and the first date to start from would be the 10th.

I have also added in an estimated delivery which would be 6 weeks after that date.

```
We will be placing our next order for this on:
    <?php
    $date = '2020/05/26';
    $weeks = 2;
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $date);
    $dateTime->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($weeks . ' weeks'));
    $dateTime->modify('wednesday');
    echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y');
    ?>

Expected delivery for the next order will be:
    <?php
    $date = '2020/05/26';
    $weeks = 2;
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $date);
    $dateTime->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($weeks . ' weeks'));
    $dateTime->modify('+42 days next wednesday');
    echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y');
    ?>
```

If anyone can confirm this is correct that would be great.